# ApplicationClass Documents.Open returns null for ASP.NET site on 64bit system

Tags: asp.net, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I have a problem with opening word document from ASP.NET site. The solution works fine on Windows 2003 Server, but doesn't work on Windows 2008 server x64 and Windows 7 x64.

To simplify the solution I've created an ASP.NET MVC 3 site and try to open word document from there.

Environment I have: Windows 7 x64 and MS Office 2010 x64

The code for opening adocument is the following:

```
    public ActionResult WordTest()
    {
        var fullFileName = @"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\fpub\TestDocument.docx";
        var impersonation = new ImpersonationManager();
        impersonation.Impersonate();
        try
        {
            var application = new Application();

            try
            {
                Type documentsType = application.Documents.GetType();
                var document =(_Document)documentsType.InvokeMember("Open", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, application.Documents,
                                               new object[] {fullFileName});

                try
                {
                    return View(new ModelData {Result = document == null ? "Bad" : "OK"});
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (document != null)
                    {
                        document.Close(false);
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(document);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                application.Quit(false);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            impersonation.CloseImpersonation();
        }
  }
```

Firstly, I make impersonation to use trusted domain user account for word interaction (ImpersonationManager is a custom component). This user has rights to open\save\close Word Application. In my tests this is my own account :)

Then I create Word application instance. WINWORD process is started under impersonated account.

But after "Open" method is invoked it always returns null. No exceptions, no info in event viewer.

Moreover Word process loads the CPU on 100% after this (1 core of CPU).

If I run the same code (without impersonation) as console application it works fine.

I wonder what can be the problem here?

**Update** It works fine if Visual Studio Development server is used as host for the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Office interop in a server-scenario (like ASP.NET, Windows Service etc.) is NOT supported by MS - see http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2

Additionally there have been several security-related changed since Windows Vista which basically make it really hard to do anything "desktop-like" in a Windows Service (IIS/ASP.NET is just a special case of Windows Service in this regard).

There are several libraries (free and commercial) to deal with Office files (without Office Interop)... to help further you need to describe your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The alternative is to use OpenXml for my solution, but currently we have to use this legacy solution. Whether impersonation doesn't help to use Word application under desktop user context rather than server context?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "context"... you can use your code fine IF you run it as a normal desktop app (NOT ASP.NET/Windows Service etc.) - this has nothing to do with impersonation...

Answer (score 1):

Regardless the accepted answer some people need to support legacy code. The solution to the problem can be found here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f5448a7-72ed-4f16-8b87-922b71892e07/word-2007-documentsopen-returns-null-in-aspnet

Comment: Agreed!  It's all well and good to sit in your ivory tower and say "everyone should use docx" but some of us have to support multiple file formats.  This link resolved the issue for me, thank you!  +1