# C# Word document fails to open

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, iis-6, ms-word

I have a website that opens a Word document on the user's browser, and fills in a certain value within the document:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string source = "c:\TemplateDocument.doc";
     string destination = "c:\Temp.doc";
      File.Copy(source, destination, true);
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application oWord;
     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document oDoc;
     oWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
     oDoc = oWord.Document.Open(destination, ReadOnly: false, Visible: false);
     oDoc.Tables[1].Rows[1].Cells[1].Range.Text = "Hello world"; // Simplified for the example
     oDoc.SaveAs2(destination);
     oDoc.Close();
     Response.Clear();
     Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
     Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;TemplateDocument.doc");
     Response.WriteFile(destination);
     Response.End();
     File.Delete(destination);

  }
```

The above code worked perfectly on our *old* server, which was IIS6.

However, we upgraded the server to IIS7, and made it work with DFS.

(DFS - basically, two replicating servers)

What happens now is that `oDoc` remains null, even after the `Open()` command.

The moment I try accessing anything within `oDoc` (such as `oDoc.Tables`), I get a `NullReferenceException`.

When running the code **locally** on the server, it works; once it's published, I get the exception.

What else might be of relevance? Code refers to the dll of Office 2010, which is the Office installed on the server (this was true also before the upgrade, so I don't think that's what is causing the problem).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe your IIS needs to run as 32bit? does IIS process have access to the office dlls? Does your IIS run as an anon user or use forms auth or using windows auth?

Comment: Windows authorization. Do you think the problem is accessing the dlls? Because the code manages to *create* the instances of `_Application` and `_Document`, but not to load the actual document.

Comment: Check http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/architecturegeneral/thread/0f5448a7-72ed-4f16-8b87-922b71892e07 does it help you? Failing that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689883/applicationclass-documents-open-returns-null-for-asp-net-site-on-64bit-system